# ¿Por qué mi modelo se ve transparente en three js GLTF?

Tags: 3d, three.js

Usé el ejemplo que viene en [esta página](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gltf#webgl_loader_gltf).

Al cargar mi modelo se ve transparente en ciertas partes; el problema de esa transparencia es que como tiene una animación donde se abre la tapa de la computadora, parece que no tiene tapa y se ve mal.

Recalco que en el ejemplo de three js el modelo no se ve así como el mío.
Usé MAYA, y usé un exportador de GLTF desde maya (instalé un script)

[image: Exportador de gltf script]

[image: TAPA CERRADA DE LA LAPTOP]

[image: Ejemplo de three js]

La pregunta en concreto es: ¿el error de visualización se debe a que debo configurar algo en el código?

```
//GLTF

        new RGBELoader()
          .setPath( 'assets/' )
          .load( 'royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function ( texture ) {

            texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

            scene.background = texture;
            scene.environment = texture;

            //render();

            // model

            const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('assets/GLTF/');
         
            loader.load('computadoratablero2.gltf', function ( gltf2 ) {
               
             
               mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf2.scene );
        
        gltf2.animations.forEach( ( clip ) => {
           
            mixer.clipAction( clip ).play();
          
        } );
        console.log(gltf2);
        //  gltf2.material.depthWrite = false;
            objetoGlobal = gltf2.scene;
          scene.add( objetoGlobal );
              //scene.add( gltf2.scene );

            //render();

            } );

          } );
        //FIN DEL GLTF
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta era
modificar el parametro de depthWrite despues de que carga el modelo

```
//GLTF

    new RGBELoader()
      .setPath( 'assets/' )
      .load( 'royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function ( texture ) {

        texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

        scene.background = texture;
        scene.environment = texture;

        //render();

        // model

        const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('assets/GLTF/');
     
        loader.load('computadoratablero2.gltf', function ( gltf2 ) {
           
         
           mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf2.scene );
    
    gltf2.animations.forEach( ( clip ) => {
       
        mixer.clipAction( clip ).play();
      
    } );
    console.log(gltf2);
    //  gltf2.material.depthWrite = false;

    gltf2.scene.traverse( function( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh ) object.material.depthWrite = true;

    } );
        objetoGlobal = gltf2.scene;
      scene.add( objetoGlobal );
          //scene.add( gltf2.scene );

        //render();

        } );

      } );
    //FIN DEL GLTF


    RESULTADO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta!